# Is there a way to get the script who's blocking browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

We have a large old web application organized with iframes (many), every iframe is a html page (to be more specific asp.net webform, but the problem is on client side).

We have a problem with some javascript but we don't know which script and in which page.

When the user navigate to a specific section of the web application, the application freeze. Browsers  generally alert the user that there is a script with long execution, and suggest to quit the script.

We can't find where is the problem. Is there some feature in modern browser to step directly in developer tools of the browser, in debug mode on the script who has the problem (instead of simply quit the script) when we face the problem, or some other workaround to detect the script?

Comment: HI, you have to set the debugger to break on all exceptions. F12>Debug tab, select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown (looks like a stop sign). It defaults with "Never break on exceptions". !important Without closing the dev tool return to your web page and do your testing.... the debugger will now break when encounters any scripting error. Long running script errors CAN occur if you have alert or prompt statements in the <head> section of your documents. Only fire alert statements after the document has loaded.

Comment: @RobParsons I don't think any script errors are actually *long running* (they all crash your page almost immediately). The usual cause for freezing pages are infinite loops, which are very hard to detect automatically.

Comment: @Goto - alert statements in infinite loops in the head section... fake support scams.

Comment: @Goto - Page 'crashes' will result in an error log in the Windows Event viewer.... always caused by browser Addons.... Long running script errors are displayed as a user message in response to long running scripts that delay the dom ready state. Place this js in a script block in the head section... while(true){alert('you have been taken');} use IE11 or Edge, v Chrome or FX.

Comment: @RobParsons But `while(true){alert('something');}` is not an error and will not trigger a breakpoint in the debugger. Also, it will not crash your page (in fact, you'll have to kill your IE by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

The comments on my answer helped for a very simple solution I didn't thinked before... Keeping the debugger running I noted on debugger toolbar (IE, but suppose every browsers work the same) the buttons "pause" (2 vertical red sticks) and "continue" (green triangle). Pressing pause the debugger stop on the exact line the script is running in that moment...

Comment: Yes, every browser dev tool works the same.... you must configure the dev tool to break on errors (handled or not) and to keep the dev tool opened while debugging.... all browsers will ignore errors while their dev tool is not opened.